# .htaccess - redirect non www to www and retain subdomains from redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, redirection

So, on my main domain 'domain.com' I created several subdomains from cPanel, like 'sub1.domain.com' and 'sub2.domain.com'. Their real location on server is in 'domain.com/sub1' and 'domain.com/sub2'.

Now, I want to redirect non www to www with .htaccess and this is what currently what i have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This works. When somebody enter domain.com it will be redirected to www.domain.com.
However when somebody enter sub1.domain.com, he will be redirected to www.domain.com/sub1 - which I don't want, it needs to be in sub1.domain.com.

What shall I add in .htaccess file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude each `sub1`, `sub2` individually like so;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub1\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Or just be specific that you only want to redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` with the `RewriteCond`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works for all domains, excluding any subdomains. have fun.

Comment: Its worked for me. for me I have to stop my subdomains from redirecting with www. After adding the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]` its worked. thanks